# Estou com dificuldade em transmitir mensagem para o usuário

Tags: javascript, html5

estou tentando fazer uma lista de nomes para sorteio usando js, html, css e boostrap ainda não ajustei as estilizações queria fazer primeiro a logica funcionar.

criei algumas funções mas creio que é na function adcCamp que preciso alterar o código para que os nomes inseridos no formulario sejam exibidos na tag

dentro das listas

estou deixando o codigo completo aqui ...

```js
function botaoAtivo() {
  alert("O Sorteio contem " + nomes.length + " participantes");
}

function sorteio() {
  var quandidade = nomes.length;
  var sorteioAleatorio = parseInt(Math.random() * quandidade);
  document.write("O nome sorteado foi o " + nomes[sorteioAleatorio])
}


function adcCamp() {
  event.preventDefault()
  var nomeLista = document.getElementById("camp");
  nomes.push(nomeLista.value);

  if (botaoAdc.onclick = true) {
    document.getElementById("camp").value = ""
  }

  var trfNome = document.getElementById("listName")

}

var nomes = [];

var inserirParticipantes = document.getElementById("calc");
inserirParticipantes.onclick = botaoAtivo;

var botaoAdivinhar = document.getElementById("adivinhar");
botaoAdivinhar.onclick = sorteio;

var botaoAdc = document.getElementById("btn")
botaoAdc.onclick = adcCamp;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .lista {
      background-color: blue;
      padding: 80px;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Sorteio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="calc" data-calc>Conectar Participantes</button>
  <button type="button" id="adivinhar" class="btn btn-warning" data-adivinhar>Sortear</button>

  <input type="text" id="camp" data-camp/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" data-btn>Adicionar</button>
  <main>
    <div>
      <ul class="list" data-list>
        <li calass="listName" data-listName>
          <p class="items"></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc precisa ter um **array** dentro da função **`adcCamp`** para poder armazenar os itens adicionados na função, da maneira que fez todas as vezes que adicionar um participante o array global será sobrescrito, como tbm o **if** ali não tem necessidade. Veja que com apenas alguns ajustes no HTML e um **for** na função consegue o resultado esperado:

```js
var nomes = [];
var inserirParticipantes = document.getElementById("calc");
inserirParticipantes.onclick = botaoAtivo;

var botaoAdivinhar = document.getElementById("adivinhar");
botaoAdivinhar.onclick = sorteio;

var botaoAdc = document.getElementById("btn")
botaoAdc.onclick = adcCamp;

function botaoAtivo() {
  alert("O Sorteio contem " + nomes.length + " participantes");
}

function sorteio() {
  var quantidade = nomes.length;
  var sorteioAleatorio = parseInt(Math.random() * quantidade);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "O nome sorteado foi o " + nomes[sorteioAleatorio];
}


function adcCamp() {
  var _nomes = [];
  var nomeLista = document.getElementById("camp");
  _nomes.push(nomeLista.value);
  
  nomes.push(..._nomes);  // Se tiver dúvidas aqui procure por spread operator
  
  nomeLista.value = "";

  var trfNome = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];
  
  for(let i=0; i<_nomes.length; i++) {
    trfNome.innerHTML += `
      <li calass="listName" data-listName>
        <p class="items">${_nomes[i]}</p>
      </li>
    `;  
  }

}
```

```css
.lista {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 80px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="calc" data-calc>Conectar Participantes</button>
<button type="button" id="adivinhar" class="btn btn-warning" data-adivinhar>Sortear</button>

<input type="text" id="camp" data-camp />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" data-btn>Adicionar</button>
<main>
  <div>
    <ul class="list" data-list></ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
</main>
```

> Acredito que esteja aprendendo, como dica nesse exercício, poderia tentar validar se o campo está preenchido, senão estiver, o botão de adicionar participante fica bloqueado.

Comment: muito obrigado estava batendo a cabeça nisso faz uns dias ! ... Quer dizer que quase todo meu código estava correto só faltava alguns ajustes no html e o for dentro da functio adcCamp?

Comment: Isso, faltava apenas os ajustes e o mais importante que era um array dentro da adcCamp.

Comment: beleza, muito obrigado me ajudou muito !